# Packing Python code into executables

Tags: python, executable

Situation: Problems importing Python modules due to some compatibility issues with the SBC I am working on. Looking to compiling them into executables.

Problem: I am not very familiar with how the compiling process works.

Question 1: Does compiling a Python code into an executable packs ALL its dependencies into the executable? I.e. am I able to run the exact same code on a different computer with no Python installed?

Question 2: Can I import a Python executable as if it is a module and use its functions?

Question 3: Can I pack a Built in Python module into an executable and have it run if Question 2's answer is "yes"?

Comment: Python is an interpreted language, and so isn't generally considered to be compiled (there's no out of the box way to create a .exe or elf binary from a batch of code). There are some tools that will essentially bundle your code with a complete python interpreter and let others run it as an executable. See cx-freeze, pyinstaller, py2exe for examples of those.

Comment: So all of the imports will be compiled together in the resulting executable?

Comment: Yes, but you won't be able to import anything from the resulting bundle.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. Would you like to post it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Yes, but in general I'd recommend you check out the docs on asking good, pointed questions for future reference ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is an interpreted language, and so isn't generally considered to be compiled (there's no out of the box way to create a .exe or elf binary from a batch of code). There are some tools that will essentially bundle your code with a complete python interpreter and let others run it as an executable. See cx-freeze, pyinstaller, py2exe for examples of those.

PyInstaller is pretty easy. For a fairly straightforward bundle, you can just

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller your_code_entry_point.py
```

See [their docs for OS specific requirements](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/requirements.html) and details